# How to make array size dependent on text file size?

Tags: java, android, arrays, text-files, streamreader

After some effort (I'm a newbie) I've managed to create a method that reads a text file and puts it into a multi dimensional array.  However the array size is hard coded and it doesn't deal with blank lines very well so I have the following questions:

1) How do I define my array to be equal to the size of the text file?

2) Is there an easy way to handle a blank line?  Ideally I'd like to just delete any blanks from the text file so that the array contains no null values but I am open to suggestions on the best way to handle it.

Here is what I have so far:

```
public void TextFileReader (){

        String[][] textFileData = new String[5][2];

        InputStreamReader InputSR = null;
        BufferedReader BufferedRdr = null;
        String thisLine = null;

        InputSR = new InputStreamReader(getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.text_file));
        BufferedRdr = new BufferedReader(InputSR);

        try {
            // open input stream text_file for reading purpose.
            int i = 0;
            while ((thisLine = BufferedRdr.readLine()) != null) {
                String[] parts = thisLine.split(" ");
                textFileData[i][0] = parts[0];
                textFileData[i][1] = parts[1];
                Log.v("String Array"+i+"0", String.valueOf(textFileData[i][0]));
                Log.v("String Array"+i+"1", String.valueOf(textFileData[i][1]));
                i = i +1;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        }
    }
```

Comment: Why not use something dynamic like [ArrayList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) where you don't have to worry about knowing the size beforehand? If you *have* to use array I suggest counting the number of rows by iterating through the file first.

Comment: No I don't need to use an array but I didn't think an ArrayList could be a multidimensional arraylist?  I guess I could just use two ArrayLists instead?

Comment: you can have an `ArrayList` of arrays.

Comment: Please refer to my answer below for an example and further explanation.

Comment: If you really must use an array: 1. Read through text file, just counting lines. 2. Dimension your array. 3. Read text file again from start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said in my comment, using [ArrayList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) in this situation makes things much simpler since you don't have to worry about knowing the size before hand. You can implement it like so:

```
ArrayList<String[]> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
try {
    // open input stream text_file for reading purpose.
    while ((thisLine = BufferedRdr.readLine()) != null) {
        if (!thisLine.isEmpty()) {
            String[] parts = thisLine.split(" ");
            arrayList.add(parts);
        }
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

---

Notice that I added the following condition:

```
if (!thisLine.isEmpty()) {
```

this makes it so that empty lines are skipped and not added to the `ArrayList`.

---

You can view the contents of your `ArrayList` by iterating through it just like you would an array:

```
for (String[] row : arrayList) {
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(row));
}
```

Or like so:

```
for (int i = 0; i < arrayList.size(); i++) {
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arrayList.get(i)));
}
```

---

I made a dummy file with the following data:

```
line one

line two

line three
```

Notice the empty lines between each line. Printing the contents of the `ArrayList` resulted in:

```
[line, one]
[line, two]
[line, three]
```

---

*If* you really want to use a double array, you could iterate through the file first and count how many non-empty lines you have just like you're doing so already (with the addition of `if (!thisLine.isEmpty()) {`) and then dimension your array like that.

---

**EDIT**
Using `ArrayList`, if you wanted to get line 2, column 2, you could do it like so  (keep in mind arrays start at index 0):

```
String[] row = arrayList.get(1);
```

Will grab the row that you want

```
String value = row[1];
```

Will grab the column of the row that you want.

Printing `value` out with `System.out.println(value);` yields in:

> two

Or you could just do it in one line:

```
String value = arrayList.get(1)[1];
```

*Or* better yet, you can create a method, so that you can call it any time:

```
public static String getValue(ArrayList<String[]> arrayList, int row, int column) {
    return arrayList.get(row)[column];
}
```

Which you can call like so:

```
String value = getValue(arrayList, 1, 1);
```

Comment: So if I wanted to reference the word (two) on line 2 in the second column would I be able to do that in the ArrayList?  I suppose instead of parsing the data into 2 columns like I did before and referencing the Array index number I could just parse the ArrayList line into 2 columns at the time of use.

Comment: @Airfix, please see my edit right above explaining how to do so.

Comment: thanks for the really detailed answer.  This is exactly what i am looking for and the detail helped me as a newbie. arrayList is way more powerful than I first thought.  Thanks so much for the help.

Answer (score 2):

For the array size problem I recommend using an ArrayList because it is dynamically allocated so you don't have to determine the size otherwise you gonna have to calculate how many rows and how many words are in the file.
For the blank line just skip on it :

```
while ((thisLine = BufferedRdr.readLine()) != null) {
     if(!thisLine.trim().equals("")){
            String[] parts = thisLine.split(" ");
            textFileData[i][0] = parts[0];
            textFileData[i][1] = parts[1];
            Log.v("String Array"+i+"0", String.valueOf(textFileData[i][0]));
            Log.v("String Array"+i+"1", String.valueOf(textFileData[i][1]));
            i = i +1;
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Is there a particular reason why you need to use an array? Arrays are usually bad practice for this exact reason: they have a static size that needs to be changed manually to avoid over-flow. In practice almost no one uses arrays unless there is a specific need to do so.

A better approach is to look at other containers that change their size dynamically, such as an Arraylist. You should be able to create an Arraylist of Arraylists that has the same effect, but doesn't offer the limitation of an array.

When coding typically try not to re-invent the wheel, just use native libraries and their features to do what you want them to do.

As for the blank line, I'd presume that when a blank line happens the String is being populated as empty, so in that case you'd just need to check if the String is empty, and then populate your container in whichever way you see fit in that case, or as the poster below suggests don't populate the container at all.

Comment: ArrayList is backed by an array

Comment: No particular reason in using an array rather than an arraylist other than I wasn't smart enough to understand what an arraylist can do for me.  I went down teh array path because I thought I needed a multidimensional array.  I guess I could just make 2 arraylists (one for each dimension of my array.  I'm not exactly sure what you mean by an arraylist of arraylists?  Can you elaborate slightly?